# Multiple vertical lines in PhpStorm for max line length

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

For years since I started using PhpStorm I had a very subtle, vertical line in the middle of the editor that was indicating the line length limit of 120 characters.

That was great and all the jazz, until recently I started having a secondary line, that's indicating the 80 chars limit.

My issue is: where does this line come from and how do I disable it? My linting rules are (and have been) always the same and those are limited at 120 chars. But the new line, the one for 80 characters... well, I don't know where it's coming from or how I disable it

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Settings, then type `Visual Guides` into the search box.

I bet you see 80, 120 or something like that.

And, I'm shocked, shocked, that you don't want to be able to store your program on 80-column Hollerith punch cards.

[image: Hollerith card]

Comment: Pretty close. `Editor` -> `Code style` -> `JS` (in my case) and `visual guides`. It was indeed set to 80, while default is set to 120. https://imgur.com/X1zUHGP
Thanks!

Comment: 80 characters tend to fit better in GitHub when performing code reviews, so 80 char max is still a good practice. I've personally been following the practice of - shooting for 80 characters max and 120 when the code can't be formatted gracefully.